# AKS cluster ingress not showing IPs

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have deployed Azure AKS using the below official terraform docs

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster

I see bunch of resources created as well as Loadbalancer called **Kubernetes** automatically

After this I have deployed deployed the Run demo app with ingress as mentioned in docs below for hello world one & two

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli

When I check the ingress resource I don't see any EXTERNAL IP address allocated & the columns are blank.

I want to set up a sample end to end AKS cluster with load balancing & a DNS record.

**Can some one let me know what am I doing wrong or is there any other repo with end to end examples?**

Comment: Can you check the output of below command: 
kubectl get svc -A 
Find the ingress controller related svc 
kubectl describe svc <ingresscontrollerservice>

Answer (score 2):

I usually recommend the following, which gives you control over the IP address etc.

- Deploy an Public IP address using Terraform (or ARM) alongside your AKS cluster
- Give the AKS Kubelet identity "Network Contributor" permissions on that PIP
- When deploying your Ingress, [reference that existing PIP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard#specify-the-load-balancer-ip-address) (and its resource group). AKS will then use that IP for the deployed service.

This way you can, for example, control whether the PIP is static or dynamic, if it's coming out of a given prefix range, etc.

Full example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip

Comment: Q1: Does the service needs to be mandatorily a LoadBalancer type when we use ingress controller? Q2: For the production cluster do you suggest Load Balancer Or application gateway?

Comment: Your actual service doesn’t have to be behind LB, ClusterIP works fine. The ingress needs to be LB. Unless you have a business need for AppGW, I would not add it. If you need WAF etc. rather look at Azure front door